# bash doing different actions for different filetypes, for all files in directory

Tags: bash, shell, sh

So I want to change the meta title of all my movies in a directory and its subdirectories

```
for file in *; do 
if [[ $file == *.mkv ]]
then
    mkvpropedit --set "title=$file" "$file"; 
elif [[ $file == *.mp4 ]]
then
    exiftool "-Title<Filename" *.mp4 -overwrite_original -r
else
    echo "$file wrong filename"
fi
done
```

That's my general idea so far, but it doesn't find the files. The commands should work, but the if conditions aren't even enterd. Also just using * doesn't search subdirectories.

Comment: You don't go into the subdirectories anywhere. Your approach works (with the exception of the incorrect invocation of `exiftool`, where the argument should contain `"$file"` instead of `*.mp4`) for files in the working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `find` commands:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec mkvpropedit --set "title={}" "{}" \;
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec exiftool "-Title<Filename" "{}" -overwrite_original -r \;
```

The first `find` recursively searches the working directory for any files with names that end in `.mkv`, and then runs the following command (i.e., the command is everything between the `-exec` and the `\;`), replacing all `{}`s with the name of the file.

The second `find` does essentially the same thing, but for files with names that end in `.mp4`.

For more info on `find`, see [its Linux man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) or [the GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Finding-Files.html#Finding-Files).

---

If you want to get just the filename to set the title, you can use the following:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'mkvpropedit --set "title=$(basename "$1")" "$1"' sh '{}' \;
```

`basename` takes a path as an argument and returns just the last part of the path (i.e., the directory name or filename).

`sh -c 'mkvpropedit --set "title=$(basename "$1")" "$1"' sh '{}'` runs `sh` with the command `mkvpropedit --set "title=$(basename "$1")" "$1"`, where the argument (`$1`) to the command is one of the filenames found by `find`. (The filename is passed as an argument this way to avoid command injections.)

Comment: awesome that works almost perfectly, for the mkv it uses not only the file name but the whole path based of the current directory. Any idea how you could just pass the filename?

Comment: @Hisfantor You will still need to pass the full path name as the final argument to the `mkpropedit` command I believe, but my addition shows how you can get just the filename for setting the title.

Comment: @Hisfantor I fixed my command for setting the `.mkv`'s title to the filename (the first one I posted was wrong).

Comment: You can do this with one `find` command: `find . -type f \( -name '*.mkv' -exec ... -o -name '*.mp4' -exec ... \)`.

Comment: @chepner I get "find: missing argument to `-exec'" if I use your structure with the command placed in instead of the ...

Comment: @ShaneBishop Not the full command (if you mean `find`), but rather the commands execute by the `-exec` primary. `find . type -f \( -name '...' -exec ... \; -o -name '...' -exec ... \; \)`. The mandatory `;`/`+` argument is what tells `find` to stop interpreting arguments as part of the `-exec` command and resume parsing them as arguments to `find` itself.

Comment: @Hisfantor, see @chepner's latest comment for where to put the `\;`s to fix your "find: missing argument to `-exec'" error.

Comment: awesome thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

With `bash` >= 4.0:

```
shopt -s globstar          # enable globstar
for file in **; do
  case "${file##*.}" in    # extract suffix
    mkv) echo "do something with $file"
         ;;
    mp4) echo "do something with $file"
         ;;
    *)   echo "unknown suffix at $file"
         ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This script will attempt to edit all relevant files in the specified directory, recursively:

```
#!/bin/sh

target_dir=${1:?no target dir provided}

cd "$target_dir" || exit 1

# pass the mkv file paths to a shell loop, to strip the leading path
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -iname '*.mkv' \
    -exec sh -c '
    for i; do
        name=${i##*/}
        mkvpropedit --set title="$name" "$i"
    done
    ' _ {} +

# exiftool can target specific extensions, and operate recursively
# use -r. to include hidden sub-directories
exiftool -r -ext mp4 -overwrite_original -Title'<Filename' .
```

Use like `/path/to/myscript /path/to/media-dir`.

File name extensions are case insensitive for both commands.

Remember that you can use `.` to target the current directory. If you want, you could change the script to use the current directory by default, if no argument is given.

I used `sh`. Writing for bash would be identical.

Comment: I think this would miss the first mp4, since you don't explicitly set a `$0` argument to `sh -c`

Comment: @ShaneBishop Whoops, I left it out. Thanks for catching it.